# Extract specific fields by the most recent date into a new column

Tags: r

So I have a snippet of the dataset and I would like to create a new column that has the action of the latest date for the same ID. If there is only one row for that ID then it will default to the only action. So the first data set is the current one and the second one is the one I want:

```
ID       date      action
1000 1975-06-23    ABC
1000 1975-06-14    CDF
1001 1975-06-23    EFG
1001 1975-06-04    HIJ
1002 1975-06-23    ABC
1003 1975-06-23    ABC



 ID       date     action  new
1000 1975-06-23    ABC    ABC
1000 1975-06-14    CDF    ABC
1001 1975-06-23    EFG    EFG
1001 1975-06-04    HIJ    EFG
1002 1975-06-23    ABC    ABC
1003 1975-06-23    ABC    ABC
```

I have tried `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(which.max(as.Date(date, '%Y/%m/%d'))) %>% select(action)` , however it crashes my R for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date),
         new = action[which.max(date)])
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   ID [4]
     ID date       action new  
  <int> <date>     <fct>  <fct>
1  1000 1975-06-23 ABC    ABC  
2  1000 1975-06-14 CDF    ABC  
3  1001 1975-06-23 EFG    EFG  
4  1001 1975-06-04 HIJ    EFG  
5  1002 1975-06-23 ABC    ABC  
6  1003 1975-06-23 ABC    ABC
```

Comment: Any idea on why it is only returning one action back for the entire column? (ABC)

Comment: You mean on your data? Not sure, you'd need to do `dput(dfname)` and copy paste the output, that way we can see where the issue lies.

Comment: Another option is that you try to reinstall `dplyr`.